# It it possible to make the :before pseudo element clickable for a phone number on iOS?

Tags: html, css

So I have a phone number in a div 555-1212 and on iOS that phone number is clickable and the phone will make a call for you, so everything works great.  Now I have attached a :before pseudo element to .phoneNum which is basically a telephone handset icon.

When a user scrolls what I do is hide the phone number div using visibility:hidden but allowing just the handset icon to show (the :before) but tapping on the handset does nothing since iOS is only recognizing the number as part of the .phoneNum div and not the :before pseudo element

Is there any clean way to have iOS recognize the whole div as the phone number including the :before part?

THanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anchor tag and start your href with tel: to force a link.

```html
<a href="tel:555-1212">555-1212</a>
```

Comment: If I do that I get this weird pop up from iOS saying the website has been blocked from automatically making a call.  The user can still allow the call, but its not as slick as the native telephone calling where iOS recognizines the number and makes it into a link

Comment: @Mark My guess is that you will not be able to achieve it otherwise, because this is probably iOS trying to prevent deceptive tactics where a malicious person shows a different number using an image and another phone number gets called.